# How to fit a multilevel model when many groups have only 1 member?

Tags: mixed-model, repeated-measures, multilevel-analysis, negative-binomial-distribution

Are there useful techniques for making it easier to optimize a multilevel model where many groups have only one member without biasing results?

I am fitting a negative binomial multilevel model with a two levels using glmer.nb in R. The equation is:

$y_i = \beta X_i + \alpha_{j[i]} + \varepsilon_i$

A large proportion of the groups have only one member.  This makes the model difficult to fit. Apparently the variance terms for these groups are 0 and the optimizer hits the boundary.

One approach I have seen is to lump all the single-member-groups into a single large "group" ($j=g$). I think this should work since the true variance of the single-member groups is 0 and so if  $i \in g$ then $\hat{\varepsilon_i} = \hat\varepsilon^*_i + \hat\alpha_g$. Where $\hat\varepsilon^*_i$ is the item level residual. Will this bias my estimates of $\beta$?

Are there other (better ?) techniques?